# Reflect control changes to DataSource using BindgSource

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox, bindingsource

I'm using WinFroms and trying to reflect control(ComboBox) changes to DataSource using BindingSource. Actualy I want to see what item is selected in comboBox.

My model is:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    public List<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
    public Foo SelectedFoo { get; set; }
}
```

Binding:

```
        List<Foo> lst = new List<Foo>();
        lst.Add(new Foo{Name="Name1"});
        lst.Add(new Foo{Name="Name2"});

        Bar bar = new Bar { Foos = lst };

        InitializeComponent();

        // bSource - is a BindingSource on the form
        this.bSource.DataSource = bar;
        // cbBinds - is a ComboBox
        this.cbBinds.DataSource = bar.Foos;
        this.cbBinds.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("SelectedItem", this.bSource, "Foos", true));
```

This code works and all Foos are displyed in cbBinding. But I also want to reflect when selected item changed in combobox. So I want Bar.SelectedFoo become equal to cbBinds.SelectedItem(not using change event of comboBox).

I can't figure out how to do this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem in your code is you set a data-binding to `Foos` property of your list while you should setup data-binding to `SelectedFoo`.

When you set up data-binding using below codes:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = List1;
comboBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("SelectedItem", Model1, "Property1", true));
```

In first line you say the combo box show all items of `List1`.

In second line, you say bind `SelectedItem` of Combo to `Model1.Property1` which means when you change selected item of combo, `Model1.Property1` will be set to selected item of combo.

So your code should be like this:

```
this.comboBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("SelectedItem", bs, "SelectedFoo", true));
```

**Note**

Reading above descriptions. now you know using a `BindingSource` is not mandatory and you can also write your code this way:

```
this.comboBox1.DataSource = bar.Foos;
this.comboBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("SelectedItem", bar, "SelectedFoo", true));
```

Comment: That's works great, thank you. A small addition: need to call this.cbBinds.Select(); becouse if you do not change selected item of ComboBox SelectedFoo property will be null.

Comment: In fact `bar.SelectedFoo` should be null because you didn't assigned a value to it and you don't  need such `combo.Select()`. But if you see calling `combo.Select()` makes a difference, in fact it sets your combo as active control and then when your control looses the focus it sets the value of `bar.SelectedFoo`.